# If $x_n \rightarrow x$ and $Ax_n \rightharpoonup y$, why does $y = Ax$?

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces

Let $X$ be a Banach space and define a linear operator $A: X \rightarrow X$. Suppose there is a sequence $(x_n) \subseteq X$ which converges to $x$ in norm. Further suppose that the sequence $(Ax_n)$ converges weakly to some $y$. Why must $Ax_n$ converge weakly to $Ax$?

Comment: Is $A$ bounded or not? If $A$ is bounded the claim is trivial.

Comment: An idea: $Ax_n$ is bounded in norm, so if $x \neq 0,$ then we can restrict $A$ to the closure of the span of $x_n$ where $A$ is bounded, so $Ax_n \to Ax$ in norm.  This leaves the case of $x=0$ to deal with (where $Ax_n$ may not converge in norm).

Comment: @BrianMoehring If $x=0$, pick an arbitrary $z \neq 0$, add it to everything and repeat your agument: since $x_n+z$ converges in norm to $z\neq 0$ and $Ax_n+Az$ converges weakly to $y+Az$, by your argument $y+Az=Az$ thus $y=0$.

Comment: @N.S. That's the second time you've made me uneasy about my thoughts.  I'm going to have to write all the steps down to just see where I've gone wrong, because together that would seem to prove that if $x_n \to 0$ and $Ax_n \rightharpoonup y,$ then $Ax_n \to 0,$ which as I mentioned at the end, I don't think we should be able to conclude that.... ....  I appreciate the comments, though.  (if nothing else, I'm learning how little of my memories of functional analysis was dealing with unbounded operators)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is false. Let $f$ be a discontinuous linear functional on $X$ and $Ax=f(x)x_0$ where $x_0$ is a fixed non-zero vector. Since $f$ is not continuous its kernel $M$ is  not closed. So there is a sequence $\{x_n\}$ in $M$ converging to some point $x$ not belonging to $M$. Now $Ax_n=0$ for all $n$ so $Ax_n\to 0$ weakly, in fact in the norm. But $y \neq Ax$ so $Ax_n$ does not tend to $Ax$.

If $A$ is a bounded operator the conclusion is true and is easy to prove: just show that $x^{*}(y)=x^{*}(Ax)$ for all $x^{*}\in X^{*}$.

Comment: If $A$ is given to be a bounded operator the conclusion follows trivially from the fact that $A$ is weak-weak continuous.